# Do I have to write the whole type of the iterator?

Tags: rust, iterator

Let's say I have an iterator like this:

```
let it = text.char_indices().take(x).skip(y);
```

Then I want to pass it to a function `my_func`. Currently I have a parameter like this:

```
fn my_func(it: std::iter::Skip<std::iter::Take<std::str::CharIndices>>) {
}
```

Is there a shorter way to write the type? Also, the function shouldn't really require that all iterator parameters now must be derived from `.skip` and `.take` and in this exact order.

Comment: `impl Iterator<Item=std::str::CharIndices>` they must be a question somewhere that already answer that

Comment: you can shorten that by specifying a custom `type`. It looks like ```type MyVerboseType = std::iter::Skip<std::iter::Take<std::str::CharIndices>>``` Then you can jusy use `MyVerboseType` instead of this long combination.